bivariate normal mutual information minus infinity
Let $$ \left[\begin{array}{c}
X\\
Y
\end{array}\right]\sim\mathcal{N}\left(\left[\begin{array}{c}
0\\
0
\end{array}\right],\left[\begin{array}{cc}
\sigma^{2} & \rho\sigma^{2}\\
\rho\sigma^{2} & \sigma^{2}
\end{array}\right]\right)$$
I need to calculate the mutual information $I(X;Y)$ where $$ \int\limits _{-\infty}^{\infty}\int\limits _{-\infty}^{\infty}f_{X,Y}\left(x,y\right)\log\left(\frac{f_{X,Y}\left(x,y\right)}{f_{X}\left(x\right)f_{Y}\left(y\right)}\right)dxdy $$
I used log rules and : $$ I\left(X;Y\right)=\iint\limits _{\mathbb{R}^{2}}f_{X,Y}\left(x,y\right)\left[\ln\left(f_{X,Y}\left(x,y\right)\right)-\ln f_{X}\left(x\right)-\ln f_{Y}\left(y\right)\right]dxdy= $$
Using marginal distributions it appears that $$ I\left(X;Y\right)=H\left(\left[\begin{array}{c}
X\\
Y
\end{array}\right]\right)+H\left[X\right]+H\left[Y\right]$$
Now according to wikipedia, the entropy of the bivariate normal vector is $$ H\left(\left[\begin{array}{c}
X\\
Y
\end{array}\right]\right)=\log\left(2\pi\right)+\frac{1}{2}\log\left(\det\left(\Sigma\right)\right)=\log\left(2\pi\right)+\frac{1}{2}\log\left(\sigma^{4}\left(1-\rho^{2}\right)\right) $$
I am asked to find the mutual information for $\rho =0 ,\rho = \pm 1$
When $\rho =0 $ then $x,y $ are independent and so the mutual information should be low.
But when $\rho=\pm 1 $ then the mutual information seems to be $-\infty $ , which contradicts a property of mutual information that says mutual information is non negative. so where did I go wrong?

There's a sign error: $I(X;Y) = h(X) + h(Y) - h(X,Y)$, not what you have written. If you work it out, $I(X;Y) = -\frac12 \log(1-\rho^2),$ and so, as $\rho^2 \to 1,$ mutual information diverges to $+\infty.$ There's also an (unimportant in this case) error in your expression for differential entropy of a bivariate Gaussian: you're missing a $+1$.

I see now, tyvm.
the +1 you speak of in the bivariate joint entropy is the e term inside the $\ln$  ?
